# Building a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, build, classpath

I would like to build a jar file with eclipse, but the program seems to copy unneccesary files into the jar.

My java gui program project consists of:

```
<path>/src/data/program.java [this is the gui]
<path>/src/data/testcases/testcase.java [here are testcases stored, which are executed by program.java]
<path>/src/data/system/config.ini [heres some data stored which is collected to set settings inside the program.java]
<path>/src/bin/.../classes.class [here are the classes stored  by eclipse(program.class / testcase.class)]
<path>/ExtRes/externallibary.jar [here are some external libaries stored]
<path>/ExtRes/Templates [here are some templates with information stored which program.java collects when used]
<path>/Img/image.png [image folder for icons inside the program]
<path>/Logs/.../somelog.txt [here are some logs stored which are output of the program.java]
```

So the progressive question is how to best sort these files.

And the underlying question is how can I generate a jar which mainly only consists of the program.java?

Edit: Thanks for the answers on the underlying question!

Please also address the question above:

**What is the common / best way to sort the files of his java gui program?**

Comment: There are some JAR Eclipse plugins that can be configured. [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project in the Project explorer, select Export, pick Java->Jar file and then you can select which classes and files to include and which do not.

Answer (score 2):

Download fatjar in eclipse as update site and http://fjep.sourceforge.net/ and use it as mentioned. It is very easy.
Or follow the step mentioned by Jakub Zaverka. You can make Runnable Jar or simply a jar as per your requirement